# Is a Cadential 6/4 tonic or dominant function?

Tags: theory, chords

A cadential <sup>6</sup><sub>4</sub> would normally occur before a V, and after an IV, ii, V/V, vii<sup>o</sup>/V, It. <sup>6</sup>, Fr. <sup>6</sup>, or Ger. <sup>6</sup>.  Does a cadential <sup>6</sup><sub>4</sub> have tonic or dominant function?  <sup>(Or... maybe... subdominant function...?)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a decoration of the dominant by a double appoggiatura, which resolves to V:

[image]

It is traditionally seen as a voice leading event rather than a distinct harmony. As such, it has a dominant function.